# Is there any statistics about auto suggestions usage when searching?

Tags: autocomplete, search-suggestion

I am thinking of using auto suggest within my company but I'm not sure if it's of any use.

Does anybody have any idea about the statistics as to how many people end up selecting an auto-suggestion versus typing their own search phrase when performing a search online with auto-suggestion capabilities?

Also, is there any difference in selection percentage (suggestion selection from all searches whether user used Auto suggest or not) on desktop versus mobile site?